# Is registerForActivityResult able to do as ACTION_CHOOSER

Tags: android, registerforactivityresult

I'm using registerForActivityResult for launch camera or gallery, but is registerForActivityResult able to do like Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER ?

```
cameraLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { success ->
        if (success) {
           // do somthing
        }
    }
galleryLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) {
          // do somthing
    }
```

In old way

```
val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
galleryIntent.type = "image/*"

val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

val chooserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, galleryIntent)
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayOf(cameraIntent))
startActivity(chooserIntent)
```

Comment: check this : 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#kotlin

Comment: @YakirMalka thanks for your answer, but still not quite clear. Should I custom a contract ?

Comment: the answer to your question is right in the link.
just scroll down abit and choose kotlin and see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did make it work by implementing `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()` which is calling the existing `onActivityResult` with same parameters as so(example in Java):

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        YourActivity.this.onActivityResult(PICK_IMAGE_ID, result.getResultCode(), result.getData());
    }
});
```

Then you just start it as:

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,     
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageURI);
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, "Choose");
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{takePhotoIntent});
if(SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
   activityForResult.launch(chooserIntent);
} else {
   //support for older than android 11
   startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE_ID);
}
```

Your `AndroidManifest.xml` also needs these queries:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Note that `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` are deprecated and will be removed sometime in the future.